# Angular 2/4 : FIlter a table using PipeTransform

Tags: angular, typescript

I used an exemple of angular2-table building and I use pipe for filtering the table.. I want to filter the table by name when I choose the "input radio"

My pipe filter :

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
    name: "dataFilter"
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: any[], query: string): any {
        if (query) {
            return _.filter(array, row=>row.name.indexOf(query) > -1);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

This is thne plnkr :
    http://plnkr.co/edit/hhv4e8WliLkmpW2Bmn3A?p=preview

How can I filter the table using input radio ?

Comment: You forgot to include your question

Comment: Yes you right .. I want to filter my table using radio button

Comment: Let me rephrase. Where are you stuck, what is causing your problems? If you have an error what are the details of the error?

Comment: Ok, if you look my plnkr, when you check a radio button, the table is not filtered

Comment: Your plunkr works fine for me.

Comment: When you check radio button ?? Try to check one button radio

Comment: I did, it works fine.

Comment: When you click on "Ralph" you got a line in the table ? I don't understand .. 4

Answer (score 0):

If you want the radio buttons to actually *display* some data you have to use appropriate values for those radio buttons that *match* the data. For example:

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="filterQ" value="Ralph" name="filterQ" /> Ralph
```

For the first radio button the value `RAP` will not match anything based on how you are using your pipe. Changing it to `Ralph` will now match one record. Also your code is case sensitive so `RALPH` will not work.

Comment: Ok, yes that was my question ... So we can't use the value for filtering .. there is not a method for matching value and label to filter??  .. like < input value = "RALPH">  match with Ralph ?

Comment: @user1814879 - your question does not make sense (to me). Yes, you can use the value to filter. See the changed input line I included in my answer? Change the value of `RAP` to `Ralph` or if you wanted to use the first 3 characters change it to `Ral` with an `l` and not `p` because `Ralph` starts with `R - a - l` and not `R - A - P`.

Comment: @user1814879 - Again, its case sensitive the way you have it written now. If you want case insensitive then turn everything into upper case in the comparison.